# VueJS - Script not loaded when direct access to subpage

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently working on a website with vue.js, and I use vue-route.

There's a subroute (/blog/post-slug) that load a script (Prism: http://prismjs.com/) and fires it in the ready() state :

```
import Prism from 'prismjs'

module.exports = {
    Route: {
        waitForData: true
    },

    data () {
        return {
            post: { }
        }
    },

    ready () {
        Prism.highlightAll()
    }
}
```

When I reach the page from a link inside the site, it’s all good, loaded and working, the result is ok in the page.

But if I reload the page or access it with a direct link from an external link, it’s not good.

Here’s my route config, if it helps:

```
/**
 * Router config
 */
module.exports = {

    /**
     * Config
     * @type {Object}
     */
    config: {
        hasbang: false,
        history: true,
        saveScrollPosition: true,
        linkActiveClass: 'site-menu__link--active',
        transitionOnLoad: true
    },

    /**
     * Before route starts transitioning
     * @param  {Object} options.from Route we are transitioning from
     * @param  {Object} options.to   Route we are transitioning to
     * @param  {Function} options.next     Progress to the next step of the transition
     * @param  {Function} options.abort    Cancel / Reject the transition
     * @param  {Function} options.redirect Cancel and redirect to a different route
     * @return {void}
     */
    before ({from, to, next, abort, redirect}) {
        next()
    },

    /**
     * After route has transitioned
     * @param  {Object} options.from Route we are transitioning from
     * @param  {Object} options.to   Route we are transitioning to
     * @return {void}
     */
    after ({from, to}) {
        if (typeof to.title !== 'undefined') {
            document.title = to.title
        }
    }
}
```

I guess something in particular happen when the view is loaded from inside the app, and not directly, but can’t find what.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Try putting prism call inside a $nextTick? Or using a document loaded event

Comment: @vbrandend it doesn't seem to work for me with a nextTick. And isn't "ready" a loaded event already ?

I managed to get it work only with a setTimeout (of 10ms), but i'd prefer to find a more "clean" way.